# Calculate DiffDays function DateTime order - Does the larger DateTime come first or second

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities, datediff

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and I am wanting to write a function that will work with both a SQL statement as well as with a List.

Here is my code:

```cs
public static class TestableDbFunctions
{
    [System.Data.Entity.DbFunction("Edm", "DiffDays")]
    public static double? DiffDays(DateTime? dateValue1, DateTime? dateValue2)
    {
        if (!dateValue1.HasValue || !dateValue2.HasValue)
            return null;

        return (double)((dateValue2.Value - dateValue1.Value).TotalDays);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the code calculates the difference in days between two `DateTimes`.

My question is this:

Should the code be

```
(dateValue2.Value - dateValue1.Value).TotalDays
```

or

```
(dateValue1.Value - dateValue2.Value).TotalDays?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not return absolute value?

Comment: Do you mean that you always want to return a positive value?

Comment: The best answer on this question I found here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/11069104/6630084](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11069104/6630084)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to compliant with SQL, the closest analogue is [DateDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms189794.aspx). The 1st argument is the `start date` and the 2nd i `end date`.  The code should be

```
return (endDate - startDate).TotalDays;
```

Comment: Can you please inform me of how to work this out myself?

Comment: @user3736648 read the reference to `DateDiff` that I supplied.